# yii-Fatal error, Call to undefined method Rights::getAuthorizer()

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, yii-extensions

Did some changes in database, and then synchronize it,it was working perfectly before changes in database, but now when an admin or anyone gets login, this error shows up, and when i refresh the page it takes me to `localhost/project/user/profile`. I set the roles that whenever an admin or owner gets login, he should redirect to the business page, but now redirecting is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the database, the problem lies in the writing of the code, make sure you must write your code in config.main like this

```
'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.*',
        'bootstrap.widgets.*',
//add this code after the above code and thats it, a small stupid mistake may cost you 3 days of hard debugging.
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*'



    ),
```